# Using GitHub Java API to retrieve info about logged in user?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github-api

I'm having trouble using this https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core library to access the Github API through Eclipse. I'm trying find and retrieve information about the currently logged in user (e.g. login, followers, repos) and print the information. I'm having trouble understanding the library, and I'm not exactly sure how to go about this with this library. I know I need to authenticate the user and to somehow retrieve the data, but I'm unsure as to how to do this or what objects to use to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation under https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core

```
//Basic authentication
GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient();
client.setCredentials("user", "passw0rd");
```

User related method should be listed at https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/UserService.java

Comment: That's actually the exact method I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: glad to hear that :)